# Find the inverse of $x^2+4x, x\ge-2$ using 3b1b quadratic shortcut

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find the inverse of $x^2+4x$ where $x\ge-2$.

Rewriting x,y:
$$x=y^2+4y$$

This is a quadratic. [Watching 3BlueOneBrown's video starting at ~ 23 minutes and 30 seconds](https://youtu.be/MHXO86wKeDY?t=1419), he shows a shortcut for calculating the quadratic.Using this method I get:

$$m = \frac{-b}{2}=\frac{-4}{2}=-2$$
$$d^2=m^2-p=-2^2-0=4$$
$$r,s=m\pm\sqrt{d^2}=-2\pm2=-4,0$$

Since I have the condition that $x\ge-2$ I know I must take only the positive sqrt so 0.

The solution in my textbook to the inverse of $x^2+4x$ where $x\ge-2$ is $\sqrt{x+4}-2$

How can I arrive at this solution? I am unable to get there with my working?

Comment: Isn't that way too complicated?  Just add $4$ to get $x+4=(y+2)^2$.

Comment: Another way to proceed is the following. Note that you can complete the squares $y^{2}+4y = y^{2}+4y +4 - 4$ so $x+4 = (y+2)^{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x^2+4x=y$

then we have $x^2+4x-y=0$

Hence $p=-y$

$$d^2=m^2-p=m^2+y=4+y$$

Hence the inverse is $$-2+\sqrt{d}=-2+\sqrt{4+y}$$